# How to get list of Stored Queries using TFPT from Command Line or bat file

Tags: batch-file, tfs-power-tools

Is there a way to get a list of stored queries using TFPT in VS 2013? I tried things like this, but that does not work.

```
tfpt.exe query /include:data "xxx\Shared Queries\Releases\*" /collection:http://tfs2013
```

Result is "The stored query could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Tfpt will only return the count, data, or headers of the query you pass to it.  Is there a specific reason you'd need to dynamically create a list of query names?  It can be done using API calls, but there'd be a lot of extra lifting to parse the name out from a WIQL (at least off the top of my head).  Storing the query names in an array either a) in the script or b) in a text file for reading would be the way to go here, imo.

If you want my thoughts on how to use the API though, let me know.